# How to Display Column of table at database in Modal using Array

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I want To Display Front/Side View of a Product in modal form, to do this I have a foreign key in my table. This is my code that I try from now.My problem is on how to display foreign key which is Prod_Dim_Image column at class = 'product_gallery' :

```
      <?php
      include('connection.php');
         $posts = array();
            $res = $conn->query("SELECT product.Product_ID,product_name,product_image,product_description,Quantity,Price,prod_dimension_image.Dim_ID,Prod_Dim_Image from product INNER JOIN
                              prod_dimension_image ON product.Product_ID=prod_dimension_image.Product_ID ");
                  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
                     {
                       $prod_id = $row['Product_ID'];
                   ?>

                                   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-9">
                             <form action="cus_order.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary text-center">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                     <h4><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                       <div>
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#updateimage<?php echo $row['Product_ID']; ?>">
                                        <img src="../img/products/mouse/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>" class="img-rounded" alt="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>" width="230" height="200"/>
                                        </a>
                                       </div>

                                        <h4>&#x20B1; <?php echo $row['Price']; ?></h4>
                                        <button type="submit" name="orderproduct"  class="btn btn-warning">Add to Cart</button>
                                     </div>
                             </div>
                             </form>
                        </div>




                        <div class="modal fade" id="updateimage<?php echo $row['Product_ID'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h4>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                  <section>
                                    <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                                             <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                               <!-- Indicators -->
                                               <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                                 <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="" class="active"></li>
                                               </ol>
                                               <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                               <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                 <div class="item active">
                                                    <img src="../img/products/mouse/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>" class="img-rounded" alt="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>" width="550" height="450"/>
                                                 </div>
                                               </div>                   
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product_gallery">
                                             <ul class="list-inline">
                                                <li>
                                                <a data-target="#img1" data-toggle="carousel-indicators">
                                                   <img src="../img/products/mouse/<?php echo $row['Prod_Dim_Image']; ?>" alt="..."  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="70" height="100" />
                                                </a>
                                                </li>
                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
                                          </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->

                                          <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                                                           <h2><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h2>
                                             <p><?php echo $row['product_description']; ?></p> <br>
                                                <br />
                                                  <div class="">
                                                     <div class="product_price">
                                                        <h1 class="price">&#x20B1;  <?php echo $row['Price']; ?></h1>
                                                     </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="">
                                                     <button type="submit" name="orderproduct" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add to Cart</button>
                                                     <button type="submit" name="wishproduct" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add to Wishlist</button>
                                                  </div>
                                           </div>                                        
                                  </div>
                              </section>
                              </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
  <?php 
                        }            
   ?>
```